# creating a log file in a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, redirect, logging

I wrote a .bat file

in order to log the activity of the .bat I tried to add a redirection with some variable
but the file isn't created.

I'm having this kind of result:

```
TYPE NUL  8h16min03s.txt 1>2014\05\29\logs\
Le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable.
```

could you help me please I don't see where the problem is:

```
@echo on
set annee=%date:~6,4%
set mois=%date:~3,2%
set jour=%date:~0,2%
set ext=.txt
set heure=%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%min%time:~6,2%s
mkdir c:\X\Y\%annee%\%mois%\%jour%\
mkdir c:\X\Y\%annee%\%mois%\%jour%\logs\
set dossier=c:\X\Y\%annee%\%mois%\%jour%
echo ### > %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%


c:\X\Y\SedeB2Bonline.exe /INI:c:\X\Y\edicom.ini

for /F %%i in ('dir /b "c:\X\Y\in\*.*"') do (

   goto EOF
)

echo Folder "IN" is empty or does not exist >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%
goto end

:EOF


echo ############################################# >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%
echo --------------------------------------------- >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%
echo Le %jour%/%mois%/%annee% : %heure% : de IN vers Source >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%
echo --------------------------------------------- >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%
echo ############################################# >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%

xcopy "c:\X\Y\in\*.*" "\\10.176.155.11\source\" /s >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%
BRC32 /DIR:"\\10.176.155.11\source\" /PATTERN:*.IN /REPLACECI:SM_:SLSRPT_ /FIXEDEXT:.EDI /EXECUTE >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%

echo ############################################# >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%
echo --------------------------------------------- >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%
echo Le %jour%/%mois%/%annee% : %heure% : de IN vers %annee% >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%
echo --------------------------------------------- >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%
echo ############################################# >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%

robocopy.exe \X\Y\in\ \X\Y\%dossier% *.IN /MOV >> %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%

:end

pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:EOF` is an internal label in CMD representing the end of the file.  Try using a different label to start with.

Also put a `pause` as shown and see if there is an error message.

```
echo ### > %dossier%\logs\%heure%%ext%
pause
```

Comment: finally its not working again:

`
C:\CORTEINGLES\SedeB2BOnLine>set heure= 9
C:\CORTEINGLES\SedeB2BOnLine>set min=26
C:\CORTEINGLES\SedeB2BOnLine>set sec=14
C:\CORTEINGLES\SedeB2BOnLine>set ext=.txt
C:\CORTEINGLES\SedeB2BOnLine>set dossier=2014\05\30
C:\CORTEINGLES\SedeB2BOnLine>mkdir 2014\05\30\
Un sous-répertoire ou un fichier 2014\05\30\ existe déjà.
C:\CORTEINGLES\SedeB2BOnLine>mkdir 2014\05\30\logs\
Un sous-répertoire ou un fichier 2014\05\30\logs\ existe déjà.
C:\CORTEINGLES\SedeB2BOnLine>echo ###  9.txt 1>2014\05\30\logs\RECUP_`

Comment: It looks like your folders already exist.  Add `2>nul` at the end of the MD command lines.  It will redirect the error messages harmlessly to nul.

Comment: oooooooook, it look fine, i added some for /F %%i in ('dir /b "c:\X\Y\...\*.*"') do (
   
   goto ...
) 

before mkdir command

Comment: that's crazy ! i still have an error
`###  5h55min00s.txt
#############################################  5h55min00s.txt
---------------------------------------------  5h55min00s.txt
Le 31/05/2014 :  5h55min00s:55:00 : de IN vers Source  5h55min00s.txt
---------------------------------------------  5h55min00s.txt
#############################################  5h55min00s.txt
0 fichier(s) copi‚(s)
Unrecognised Parameter: 5h55min00s.txt
Unrecognised Argument: h55min00s.txt
One or more arguments were invalid. Rename aborted.`

Comment: i think i know why, its because of %heure% giving " 5" there is a space before 6 instead of "05"

Comment: i put this and its ok
`: Sets the proper date and time stamp with 24Hr Time for log file naming
: convention

SET HOUR=%time:~0,2%
SET dtStamp9=0%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
SET dtStamp24=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

if "%HOUR:~0,1%" == " " (SET dtStamp=%dtStamp9%) else (SET dtStamp=%dtStamp24%)`